# Regex to cut hostname

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I am trying to cut my hostname, to two 'sections' from the left.  A hostname would look like:

```
servername-01.location.domain.com
```

or

```
servername-01.location.test.domain.com
```

I need to cut this to the below:

```
servername-01.location
```

For the reason that some domain names have longer "suffixes", I do need to take the first two "sections" up to the second '.', but excluding the second '.'.

I used the below to cut the hostname from the back, but then realised the suffix's amount of subdomains may change, so this no longer works:

```
${HOSTNAME%.*.*}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
SHORTHOST=$(cut -d "." -f 1-2 <<< $HOSTNAME)
```

which will cut the original hostname into fields at every period `.` and print out only the first two.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I used this, I just missed how cut can do "1-2" when I tested earlier.  My current usage is:
SHORTHOSTNAME=$(echo ${HOSTNAME} | cut -d"." -f 1-2)

Comment: You're welcome! If you found the answer helpful, please consider accepting it so that other people with similar questions can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it's hard to remove a variable part like that with one parameter expansion. But there's a roundabout way of doing it, we can first remove the two first segments (which we actually want to keep), leaving the tail end, and then use *that* as the part to remove from the original string.

So:

```
$ hostname=servername-01.location.test.domain.com
$ echo "${hostname%.${hostname#*.*.}}"
servername-01.location
```

(`.${hostname#*.*.}` is `.test.domain.com` and then `${hostname%.test.domain.com}` is `servername-01.location`.)